# VB.NET and Mysqldump

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Currently I have a project in VB.NET that has a feature of backing up and restoring mysql dumps using the Mysqldump found in my bin directory of mysql workbench

I am hosting my server online and i still need that function in my application.
But to do that, the client PC should install mysql workbench first to use that feature.

Is there any workaround with this? Still use the feature without installing MySql Workbench in the client PC? Like copying the whole BIN folder of MySql, is that even possible?

Comment: there is a good NuGet package called MySqlBackUp that probably does what you want.

Comment: can i use that to dump my database ?
my db has blob datatypes so i am using mysqldump

Comment: Thanks man! You are a life saver, i can now bakcup and restore my database without having to install mysql workbench